# Help with proving a set is open in the complex plane

Tags: analysis, continuity

I was trying to prove that $\{ ∈ ℂ :|z^2 - 25| < 3\}$ is open. I tried using the distance formula and the polar representation but couldn't really understand what this would look like. I just need help with understanding what this set looks like and I should be able to do the rest.

It's been pointed out that I can just do it through continuity but I haven't gotten to that part yet and I want to try it with the open ball definition.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f:\mathbb{C}\to [0,\infty ),\, z\mapsto |z^2-25|$ is continuous, hence $f^{-1}([0,3))$ is open, as the set $[0,3)$ is open in $[0,\infty )$.∎

Comment: Or less scary for newbies: The function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb R,\, z\mapsto |z^2-25|$ is continuous, hence $f^{-1}((-\infty,3))$ is open, as the set $(-\infty,3)$ is open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I should mention we haven't proven continuity yet so I was trying to use an open ball definition to solve it

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you need to know what it looks like. Note that $g:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$
g(z) := \lvert z^2-25 \rvert - 3
$$
is a continuous function. Also:
$$
\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}: \lvert z^2 - 25 \rvert < 3 \rbrace = g^{-1}\left( (-\infty, 0)\right)
$$
Since $(-\infty, 0)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is continuous, your set is open.

Comment: I haven't gotten to the continuity section yet so I was trying to prove it with the open ball definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you wanted to try things with the open ball definition:

Denoting $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z^2 - 25| < 3 \}$ by $S$, it suffices to show that for $z \in S$ there exists an open ball $B_z$ which is centered at $z$ and is contained in $S$.

For $z \in S$, $|z^2 - 25| < 3 - \epsilon$, $\epsilon > 0$. Now pick $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta^2 + \delta|z^2 - 25| < \epsilon$. Define $B_z$ by $B_z = \{z_1 \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_1| < \delta\}$. Then for $z_1 \in B_z$, $|z_1^2 - 25| = |z_1 + 5||z_1 - 5| = |z_1 - z + z - 5||z_1 - z + z + z| \leq \left (|z_1 - z| + |z - 5| \right )\left(|z_1 - z| + |z + 5|  \right)$ $= |z_1 - z|^2 + |z^2 - 25| + |z_1 - z||z^2 - 25| < \delta^2 + 3 - \epsilon + \delta|z^2 - 25| < 3.$ So $B_z \subset S$, hence $S$ is open.